# Does my home have a main breaker? If not, is this something that could be added?

Tags: electrical

My house was built in 1998, it has one electrical panel inside of the house. This panel has a blank spot which says “Main”, but no breaker is installed here.

Outside the house attached to the power meter I see what appears to be a door, could the main breaker(s) be located in here? Is this something I can touch/open?

Comment: (: Oops! Close the panel cover and delete picture from the internet! Don't let anybody see the bottom breakers that are not UL/CSA/ETL Listed for use in that panel! You need to get those replaced with GE breakers listed on door (or more expensive breakers "classified" for use in multiple panels).

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Thanks for the tip! I didn't realize there was any compliance or code issues with anything in the panel, I will contact an electrician

Comment: Looks like the remains of a lead seal  under the meter.

Comment: I don't think @NoSparksPlease  really meant for you to delete the picture, probably pulling your leg. Yes, wrong breakers but some of the good guys here could tell you what to look for.

Comment: The three BR breakers in the bottom slots should be changed out to GE THQL115 when able.  They are $6 each normally.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thanks much, I will have this done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main breakers will be in the cabinet next to the electric meter. You should be able to pull the lid up from the bottom after pushing  that tab down. This is safe to do.

Comment: The door on the right with the duck. Don't touch the door on the left with the meter in it (It should have a "seal" preventing that, but I can't see it.)

Comment: There is a blue tamper seal on top of the meter.

Comment: Thanks, sure enough the main 200a break was there